# Customized color doesn't work for theme color in Metropolis

Tags: beamer, color, beamer-metropolis

I used the code below to setup my template in beamer. It only gave the defualt theme color. Would anyone please tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks.

```
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.19,0.55,0.91}
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you want to use the color theme structure?

Comment: Thanks for editing my original post! I watched a tutorial when I started using beamer. The instructor said that you have to use structure whenever you use a customized color. I tried my code without structure. It didn't work either. I don't know what else I should use.

Comment: Well, the instructor was not fully right. Which color do you want to change?

Comment: I'd like to change the default theme color(dark greenish) to "myblue". Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just a word of advice: You should use the metropolis color theme when you use metropolis. There's a simple way to adjust the colors documented in section 3.2 of the manual.

Here's what a corrected version of your code would look like (do not use the main theme, just the components).

[image: custom]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{metropolis}
\useoutertheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.19,0.55,0.91}
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Test
    \end{frame}
    \section{Blub}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Test
    \end{frame}
    \section{Quack}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* The following uses the custom color just for the dark gray (not green) parts (title).

[image: frame title]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.19,0.55,0.91}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

%\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=myblue}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{exampleblock}{Test}
            ADF
        \end{exampleblock}
    \end{frame}
    \section{Blub}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Test
    \end{frame}
    \section{Quack}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to change the dark green bar part to blue and keep the text in black. Sorry, I'm still learning how to post properly. lol

Comment: @ScarlettQOM Dark green bar? The bar is orange by default (and the backround of the title gray).

Comment: @ScarlettQOM See my updated post.